# В чем смысл запечатывания класса

Tags: c#, .net

Зачем может потребоваться запечатывать класс и припятстывать наследыванию?

Например, есть класс `FileInfo`, который запечатан. Почему что бы его расширить я вынужден воспользовать композицией или методами расширения?

Дать разработчикам этого класса понимание того, что от него никто не наследуется => могут свободно его менять? Спорное утверждение, ведь композиция тоже может легко поломаться или методы расширения, которыми костыльными методами добивались недостающей функциональности(если в будущем появится реальный метод с таким именем).

Comment: Если класс запечатан - то это значит, что он не предназначен для наследования разработчиками. То есть разрабы не хотели, чтобы кто то наследовался от класса, переопределял поведение методов или делал что то ещё подобное, и также весь код, что написан разработчиками и использует этот класс не ожидает встретить наследника этого класса.

Comment: [When and why would you seal a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7777611/2881286)